# JavaFX- how to call setCellValueFactory for all rows even if they are not showing?

Tags: javafx, rendering, tableview

My tableview contains more rows than what it can show so it automatically adds a vertical scrollbar, the problem is that I have some code I want to run with the setCellValueFactory method but this method doesn't get called until the rows are rendered, is there a way to force this code to run even if the rows are not showing?

```
TableColumn<Row, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column");

    col
            .setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Row, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(
                        final CellDataFeatures<Row, String> p) {
                    System.out.println("Should run before rendering");
                    return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper("Value");
                }
            });
```

Comment: No. Why do you want to force it to run?

Comment: Because I want to get the values of some rows but their values change only when the setCellValueFactoy method is called.

Comment: You can get the values from the data: i.e. `for (Row row : table.getItems()) {System.out.println(row.getXXX());}` where `XXX` is the name of the property displayed in the column. The cell value factory is just a function that you provide to the table column to tell it how to get the value from a given row object: it doesn't store the data. Perhaps you need to edit your question to provide a bigger view of what you are trying to do, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).